# How can I open multiple SharePoint files based on a specific column data, from a web page?

Tags: sharepoint, metadata

I tell you my need:

From a web page that I administer on a VPS not linked to Microsoft/Sharepoint, I would like to open on other tabs several files stored on a sharepoint site, of which I only have one column data.

For example assuming that the column of my Sharepoint library is "Country", I would like to open in new tabs all the files tagged "France".

I don't know how to transform my "France" column data into a list of hyperlinks corresponding to these files in sharepoint.

I'm more PHP but open for a solution using any other programming language.

Many thanks for your help!

I tried to find the solution of my problem in Sharepoint documentation and in forums, but i couldn't find the answer

Comment: Up!__________________